# Get a specific pixel sized image from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am complete newbie when it comes to Google Earth Engine, but I would like to learn and am currently facing the following problem: I wanted to get the images from GEE into Google Colab so that I can play with them using Numpy. I have learnt from the forums and posts that the maximum sized array I can take is 512x512 (or 262144 pixels in total).
Is there a way, given a starting coordinates, that I can generate other three coordinates of a rectangle, such that I will receive a 512x512 pixel sized image?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have actually managed to overcome this problem, I decided to share my solution.
So by printing the meta-data information of the image I managed to get the size of the picture in terms of pixels. Knowing the coordinates of the left bottom-most and right top-most points, I could construct two simple linear equations where I approximated the change in X coordinates with the pixel size of the image and of course the same for the Y coordinates.

Eq. X: px_X_axis * x = delta_X_coordinates

Eq. Y: px_Y_axis * y = delta_Y_coordinates

Note, a pixel for longitude is not the same length, in terms of coordinate degrees, as a pixel for latitude!